# error login page in asp.net oledb

Tags: asp.net, authentication

i been having problem   in compiling a simple login page in asp

default.aspx.vb
Imports System.data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\jensen\My Documents\login.mdb;Persist Security Info=True")
    cn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select user,pass,Type from login Where user= '" & tb_user.Text & "' AND pass = '" & tb_pass.Text & "' AND Type= '" & tb_type.Text & "'", cn)
  Dim ***dr*** As New OleDbDataReader()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    If dr.Read = True Then
        MsgBox("verification successfull")
    Else
        MsgBox("invalid username")
    End If
    cn.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class
error 1:type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' has no constructors.
when the error is clicked the 
  'Dim dr As New OleDbDataReader()'
the "dr" is highlighted
help me out of this single errror 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OleDbDataReader doesn't have an empty constructor.
Try:

```
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

instead of:

```
Dim ***dr*** As New OleDbDataReader()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```